# Migrating Ubuntu 18.04 Server

Tags: 18.04, webserver

Is there an easy way to migrate an Ubuntu 18.04 server with a LEMP stack and Wordpress website from one computer to another (different CPU and motherboard)?

Comment: Does WordPress have a migrate tool or plugin?  This should be fairly easy to back up and restore to another wordpress base installation, but I would not recommend trying to "migrate" your entire Ubuntu installation to a PC with different hardware.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by the comments - do not migrate 1:1 ubuntu instalation on a different hardware - there's a big chance you'll end up with broken system on the new computer.

to migrate:

1. install ubuntu on new HW
2. install LAMP stack
3. migrate DB - mySQL migration guide here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-mysql-database-between-two-servers
4. migrate wordpress PHP installation (simple rsync of /var/www/ shoud do it)
5. start it up and check if everything's working as expected

bonus step: learn ansible and automate your deployment for future migrations :)